# C# DataGridView reentrant call Error

Tags: c#, datagridview

Not sure exactly what is going on. I'm trying to change the column cell type to a combo box when the cell is entered. It works fine for every row execept when the RowIndex and ColumnIndex are the same. When I select that row/column I get the "Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.

```
dgv1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.ColumnIndex == dgv1.Columns["ColumnName"].Index)
  {
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cmbCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

    foreach(string v in values)
    {
      cmbCell.Items.Add(v);
    }

    dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["UnitEchelon"] = cmbCell;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and the error you are reporting does not appear when `RowIndex` equals `ColumnIndex`, but when the given cell is already of `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` type. Thus, this error can easily be avoided via:

```
if (dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["UnitEchelon"].GetType() != typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxCell))
{
    dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["UnitEchelon"] = cmbCell;
}
```

Note that, although the given type (combobox, text, etc) is set at the     cell level, the initial types are created at the column level (when the column is inserted). What you are doing might be considered as not-100%-right/expectable: all the cells in the column are assumed to have the same type; and you are not changing the type of the cell by relying on a property for this purpose (e.g., `EditType`), but just by making an assignation to a variable with the target type. This last comment is to somehow explain a so inflexible behaviour (why it doesn't perform changes back and forth without triggering an error).

Comment: the easiest explaination would likely be ignorance. The data grid's datasource is set to a List<class> where the class property i'm trying to display is a string value derived from a list of acceptable values. based on your guidance, I will look at leverging EditType.

Comment: @Brad Bear in mind that EditType is not as straightforward as "your approach". The ideal situation would be setting the column types at the start, when adding each column. Bear in mind that by adding a DataGridViewComboBoxCell type column, all the cells on it will get this type by default. Sample code (all the cells in col 1 comboboxes): DataGridViewComboBoxColumn curCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
curCol.Name = "col 1";
curCol.Items.Add("item1");
curCol.Items.Add("item2");
dgv1.Columns.Add(curCol);